# Executing gulp in php returns error but works in shell

Tags: php, node.js, shell, gulp

I have a wierd problem with executing gulp from php script. Tests:

```
browser: http://server.com/pull.php <- does not work
shell: php pull.php <- works
shell: gulp <- works
```

Here is my setup:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Node v5.6.0
PHP 5.5.30-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:14:34)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

Here are packages in package.json:

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.5.2",
"gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.6",
"gulp-watch": "^4.3.5"
```

It works perfectly when i run this from shell but returns error when run in php as webserver:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'existsSync'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/lib/find_config.js:21:10
    at Liftoff.buildEnvironment (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:67:20)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:192:32)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:185:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:159:9
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:99:14
    at Array.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:38:7)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Command to run it is simple:`passthru('gulp 2>&1');`. I hoestly don't know what is wrong, owner of the files, web server (nginx runs as) user and git owner is the same user named `git`. Tried various different things as making bash script to run it from php but no luck. I am guessing i am missing some system variables?

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out node couldn't play nicely with gulp. My solution:

```
passthru('node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js 2>&1');
```

I can't explain why, just tried few random ideas and that one worked. One thing bothers me though, why can't i get full info on `git pull`? I am only getting:

```
Updating dcd958f..db05960
```